# 'object 'startsWith' not found' error while trying to compile R code

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to compile my R code which makes use of LaTeX to generate PDF report. The code reads in excel file and processes it by using some functions from packages like xtable, gdata and data.table. One of the such function is 'startsWith' which is in gdata. Here is a sample code with uses startsWith:

```
#define some integer variables 
    inLen <- as.integer(0)
    outLen <- as.integer(0)


for (i in length(some_array):1) {

   #some processing here 

   if (startsWith(string, "<<")) {
     inLen <- inLen + as.integer(some_array[[i]][2])
   } else if (startsWith(string, ">>")) {
     outLen <- outLen + as.integer(some_array[[i]][2])
   }
```

Although I have installed this package, my code always throws out following error when it refers to this 'startsWith' function:

```
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED.

gdata: read.xls support for 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files ENABLED.

Attaching package: ‘gdata’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    nobs

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    object.size


Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:gdata’:

    first, last


Error:  chunk 1 
Error in get(name, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'startsWith' not found
```

I am unable to figure out why its complaining about it when the package containing is already loaded.

Comment: Please show your R command that is generating the error.

Comment: @Edward, Just added some code snippets

Comment: I can't reproduce any error with that code snippet. Please provide a _reproducible example_.

Comment: Does prefixing with `gdata` like so: `gdata::startsWith(string, "<<")` solve it?